How can I format Pino logger output in the browser console?
I am using pino with next.js.
I have the following config:
import pino from "pino"
import { Logger } from "pino"

const baseLogger: Logger = pino({
  level: process.env.PINO_LOG_LEVEL || "info",
  browser: {
    serialize: true,
  },
  transport: {
    target: "pino-pretty",
    options: {
      colorize: true,
      messageFormat: "[{group}] {msg}",
    },
  },
})

export default baseLogger.child({ group: "app" })

export const authLogger = baseLogger.child({ group: "auth" })

This works great on the server and gives me colourised / formatted output with a timestamp and log level.

However when I use the logger on the client, I don't get any formatting in the browser console:

How can I add timestamp and log level to the messages logged to the client?

Probably helpful: https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/HEAD/docs/browser.md
Have you checked that?

@KostasMinaidis thanks. Yeah I had but went down a bit of a rabbit-hole with pino-pretty, but I think the best thing to do is to skip that in the browser and use the browser.write formatting function.

Here is a solution that mimics the colouring and content of pino-pretty but in the browser (Other than the process ID which makes no sense in the client).
The key is forgetting about pino-pretty altogether as it doesn't work in the browser, and formatting the logging message by hand using pino's browser.write hook.
Note that if you're using next.js, this also ensures that the browser logging that next also outputs to its own log are correctly coloured too, including middleware logging.
import pino from "pino"
import { Logger } from "pino"
import { format } from "date-fns"

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Const
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const COLOR = {
  GREEN: `\x1b[32m`,
  RED: `\x1b[31m`,
  WHITE: `\x1b[37m`,
  YELLOW: `\x1b[33m`,
  CYAN: `\x1b[36m`,
}

const LEVEL_COLORS = {
  FATAL: COLOR.RED,
  ERROR: COLOR.RED,
  WARN: COLOR.YELLOW,
  INFO: COLOR.GREEN,
  DEBUG: COLOR.GREEN,
  TRACE: COLOR.GREEN,
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Base Logger
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const baseLogger: Logger = pino({
  level: process.env.PINO_LOG_LEVEL || "info",

  browser: {
    write: (logObj) => {
      const { level, msg, group, time } = logObj as Record<string, string>

      const levelUppercased = level.toUpperCase()

      const timeFormatted = format(new Date(time), `HH:mm:ss.sss`)

      const LEVEL_COLOR =
        LEVEL_COLORS[levelUppercased as keyof typeof LEVEL_COLORS]

      console.log(
        `[${timeFormatted}] ${LEVEL_COLOR}${levelUppercased} ${COLOR.CYAN}[${group}] ${msg} ${COLOR.WHITE}`
      )
    },
    formatters: {
      level: (label) => {
        return {
          level: label,
        }
      },
    },
  },
  transport: {
    target: "pino-pretty",
    options: {
      colorize: true,
      messageFormat: "[{group}] {msg}",
    },
  },
})

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Child Loggers
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const logger = baseLogger.child({ group: "app" })

// Auth logger
export const authLogger = baseLogger.child({ group: "auth" })

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Exports
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

logger.info("Using pino logger")

export default logger

